# how to manage Css Floats

Tags: html, css

[image: counter]

I need to make something like this.
How do i manage the floats of the text, image and the number. Cant seem to get the text right.

i used span for all three and set background for the image of the span.
is there any better way to do this? and how do i get it as this.
Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/yapamjfy/

```
.counter-inner ul li{
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.counter-image {
  display: block;
  width: 58px;
  height: 70px;
  border-right: 2px solid #fc6867;
  background: red;
}

.counter-text{
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
.counter-inner {
  width: 763px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.counter-inner ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.counter-inner ul li {
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.counter-image {
  display: block;
  width: 58px;
  height: 70px;
  border-right: 2px solid #fc6867;
  background: red;
}

.counter-image.first {
  background: url('../images/counter-1.png') center center no-repeat;
  float: left;
}

.counter-number {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 17px;
}

.counter-text {
  float: left;
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left:-15px;

}
ul li
{
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/yapamjfy/1/)

Comment: Dat's ok sir @user3783888 MY pleasure